# altjs react store connection not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm trying to connect my stores to the actual app in order to provide data and react to state changes. Sadly though, the store connection seems to be faulty.

```
 @connectToStores
 class App extends Component {

     static getStores() {
        return [CategoryStore, UserStore, LocalizationStore];
     }

     static getPropsFromStores() {
         return {
            ...CategoryStore.getState(),
            ...UserStore.getState(),
            ...LocalizationStore.getState()
     };
   }

    static componentDidConnect(props, context) {
         ca.fetchCategories();
         la.fetchLocales();
     }
```

The componentDidConnect never gets used when running the project.  According to this: https://github.com/altjs/connect-to-stores/issues/6 that function should run as soon as the stores have been connected.
I had it working partially putting the action in componentWillMount, but the states aren't updated properly. So I think the store connect isn't set up properly.

I also tried both the ES7 decorator / ES6 normal implementation.

I have no clue why data from the stores isn't properly distributed. any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason why the props weren't passed down to the childeren due to the following:

I used this to initialize the children:

```
 const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, this.state);
 });
```

Which passes down the state but not the props. hence replacing this.state with this.props worked for me.